# How can I access attachment metadata within lektor templates?

Tags: templates, metadata, attachment, lektor

I am following the lektor guide to set up a [portfolio](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/guides/portfolio/) site. My goal is to include a caption below each image displayed using the `projects.html` and `project.html` templates.

My first thought was to use [attachment metadata](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/content/attachments/), as that would make it simple to customize the caption content for each image attachment. However, I was unable to find any documentation or examples on how to achieve the desired result.

As an example, assume I have created a project page `first-project` and added an attachment `image001.jpg` to the project. The metadata file path for this attachment is `/content/projects/first-project/image001.jpg.lr` and here are its contents:

```
_model: image
---
description: An example caption for image001.jpg
---
photographer: Photographer
---
copyright: 2023 by Photographer
```

How can I access these metadata fields from within the `projects.html` and `project.html` templates?

I have tried accessing them from the image object created within the template (e.g. `{{ image.description }}`, `{{ image.photographer }}`, etc.) but nothing is returned.

I am also aware that other [image data](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/templates/imageops/) can be accessed via templates such as `image.width`, `image.height`, `image.exif.description`. Although I could use something like the EXIF description it would be preferable to avoid including the caption text within the image EXIF data if possible.

Is using attachment metadata a reasonable method for achieving my goal? Would it be simpler to just use the description field in the image EXIF data? Or instead should I be using a different approach as this is not the intended purpose of attachment metadata? (e.g. something like [content flow](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/content/flow/)).

Any feedback or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using attachment metadata. The additional requirement is to create a a model `/models/image.ini` with the desired fields:

```
[model]
name = Image
label = {{ this.title }}

[fields.description]
label = Description
type = string

[fields.photographer]
label = Description
type = string

[fields.copyright]
label = Copyright
type = string
```

The fields can then be referenced within the template (e.g. `{{ image.description }}`). If the model has a different name such as `img.ini` then this should be included in the metadata file `image001.jpg.lr`:

```
_model: img
---
description: An example caption for image001.jpg
```

Comment: Why you  answer your own question? Wired.

Comment: After further investigation I identified the solution to my question. I figured I would provide an answer so other users might benefit from the example as well.